# Cannot assign value of type 'V' to type some 'Protocol'

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a protocol:

```
import SwiftUI

...

protocol MyProtocol : View
{
    var aValue: CGFloat { get }
}
```

Then I have a property in a `UIViewController`:

```
var contentView: some MyProtocol = MyView()
```

Where `MyView` is:

```
struct MyView : MyProtocol
{
    var aValue: CGFloat = 0.25

    var body: some View
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Back in my view controller I have:

```
func showView<V: MyProtocol>(view: V)
{
    ...

    contentView = view // ERROR Happens here.
}
```

> Cannot assign value of type 'V' to type 'some MyProtocol'.

Why do I get this error and how can it be avoided?

Comment: Does `BottomSheetContentViewProtocol` conform to `MyProtocol`?

Comment: `BottomSheetContentViewProtocol` isn't `SomeProtocol`. Also you shouldn't use `some` in this case.

Comment: @Asperi Forgot to replace with real name in my code with `MyProtocol`

Comment: @Sweeper Forgot to replace with real name in my code with `MyProtocol`.  Without `some` I got other issues: https://stackoverflow.com/q/71057533/1971013 (the initialisation ` = MyView()` was a hack to avoid this earlier issue).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var contentView: some MyProtocol = MyView()
```

So the type of `contentView` is "some specific, secret (opaque) type, unknown to anything but the compiler, that conforms to MyProtocol, and also happens to be exactly MyView, even though nothing can know that." It's not "something that conforms to MyProtocol" which it seems maybe you're thinking it is. If you mean that, the syntax is:

```
var contentView: MyProtocol = MyView()
```

The point of `some` is that the type is statically known at compile-time by the compiler, but not known to the caller, or by anything else.

For example, even this would fail:

```
var contentView: some MyProtocol = MyView()

contentView = MyView() // Cannot assign value of type 'MyView' to type 'some MyProtocol'
```

The compiler will not prove that MyView is exactly the secret type that `contentView` used. (For most errors of this type I'd say the compiler "cannot prove," but in this case, it's an active decision to forbid proving the fact because that's what `some` does.)

That "secret" type is carried along, however, and is well defined, it's just opaque. For example, the following is fine:

```
var contentView: some MyProtocol = MyView()
let otherView = contentView // otherView is definitely the same as as contentView
contentView = otherView     // so it can be assigned
```

At first pass, I expect the code you want is just the above `var contentView: MyProtocol`, but it's very possible you have a deeper misunderstanding about SwiftUI. You cannot just swap in arbitrary Views in SwiftUI. As a rule, everything should be decided at compile-time, not runtime. There are tools like AnyView to work around this, but generally should not be your first choice. I expect there's a deeper design problem here that isn't in your question.

For more details of opaque types, see [SE-244](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0244-opaque-result-types.md).

Comment: Is there a value that you can give to `var contentView: some MyProtocol` that would not cause an error?

Comment: @mfaani I expect that the answer is no, but I don't quite understand the question. What kind of value are you thinking of?

Comment: nothing tbh. Just trying to understand the syntax. I'm trying to figure out why it works with getters i.e. `var body: some View {...}` but then you can't directly set it yourself...

Comment: @mfaani Sure. Edited to call out this situation and give an example where you could assign something to `contentView`.

Answer (score 2):

See Rob's answer for a good explanation of why, currently, your view controller is generic as follows and you haven't realized it.

```swift
final class ViewController<View: MyProtocol> {
  private(set) var contentView: View

  init(contentView: View) {
    self.contentView = contentView
  }

  func showView(view: View) {
    contentView = view
  }
}
```

The property initializer you're using only applies to one of the potentially infinite `ViewController`s that may be.

```swift
extension ViewController where View == MyView {
  convenience init() {
    self.init(contentView: .init())
  }
}
```